# Can I get a return value from an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, alert

Let's say I use type:"email", can I get a true or false? since input type already have their own validation.

I want to use it in a javascript and if i can just do this (this is just an example code)

```
const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
if(email == true){
  window.alert(true);
};
```

if user put the correct email, then it will pops an alert.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#methods — checkValidity

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HTMLInputElement#checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#methods):

```js
const email = document.getElementById('input');

function test() {
  if (email.checkValidity()) {
    window.alert(email.value);
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="input"><button onclick="test()">Verify</button>
```